# PreferenceFragment can't load from XML (ClassCastException)

Tags: android

I'm having some difficulties getting a PreferenceFragment to load using XML.
It keeps throwing a **ClassCastException** "PreferenceFragmentClass cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment".
The code is intended to run on API14 and higher.

Here's my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    }   
}
```

Here's the code where SettingsFragment is being used in:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class FragmentsSetup extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsAdapter tabsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        viewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(viewPager);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, viewPager);
        tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.forwarding_tab).toUpperCase()), ForwardingFragment.class, null);
        tabsAdapter.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.settings_tab).toUpperCase()), SettingsFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace, and please post the code where you are using `SettingsFragment`.

Comment: It will work better if you use the "edit" link under the question to edit the question to contain these additional materials.

Comment: Yeah, figured that out :) it's up there now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SettingsFragment` inherits from `PreferenceFragment`. `PreferenceFragment` is from the native API Level 11 implementation of fragments. However, `FragmentsSetup` is inheriting from `FragmentActivity`, from the Android Support package's backport of fragments.

That combination will not work.

If you intend to support devices older than API Level 11, you cannot use `PreferenceFragment`. Also, I am uncertain if `PreferenceFragment` works outside of a `PreferenceActivity` (it might, but I have never tried that).

Comment: Thanks, I'll explore different ways to properly set up the settings.

Comment: Confirming ```PreferenceFragment``` works in a normal ```Activity```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for Android 3.0 (API level 11) and higher, you should use a PreferenceFragment to display your list of Preference objects. 
Also you can add a PreferenceFragment to any activity—you don't need to use PreferenceActivity.

See documentation here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?